# Post запрос с помощью библиотеки requests к fastapi выдает 422 ошибку

Tags: python, post, fastapi

С помощью библиотеки requests пытаюсь передать post запрос на url с fastapi. Получаю ошибку: "422 Unprocessable Entity".
Код fastapi:

```
@app.post('/message')
async def mail(destinations: List[str], message: str, event_type:str, selected_services: List[str], company: List[str] = ['False']):
```

Код для отправки post запроса на url:

```
payload = {'destinations': destination, 'message': message,'event_type': event_type, 'selected_services' : selected_services}
requests.post("http://localhost:8000/message", json=payload)
```

Сам payload выглядит примерно так:

```
{'destinations': ['123'], 'message': '{"values": [{"amount": 23232}, {"timestamp": 123323, "name": "TEST"}]}', 'event_type': 'START', 'selected_services': ['e-mail']}
```

Ранее делал это просто с помощью вызова функции в модуле main следующим образом:

```
asyncio.run(main.mail(destination, message,event_type, selected_services))
```

Однако сейчас возникла необходимость добиться того же результаты с помощью post запроса.
Возможно кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: `company: List[str] = [False]` — ну как минимум тут несоответствие между аннотацией и значением

Comment: Так понял, сейчас кавычки добавлю посмотрим.

Comment: C любой строкой все равно та же ошибка.

Comment: Есть какой-нибудь более полный текст ошибки? Наверняка fastapi написал что-нибудь в теле ответа?

Comment: От фаст апи ответ краткий: INFO:     127.0.0.1:54922 - "POST /message HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity

Comment: С asyncio.run через модуль все работает, но при попытке сделать то же самое по url ошибка.

Comment: Тут явно нету тела ответа, смотрите именно тело ответа

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147336/discussion-between-leteers-and-andreymal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:
Заменил в async def mail типы в message и event_type на List[str]. После этого они переместились из Parameters в Request body, что позволило так же передать их через json.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]